# LateInitializationError: Field 'authProvider' has not been initialized

Tags: flutter, dart

I got the error `LateInitializationError: Field 'authProvider' has not been initialized.` for the following:

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State createState() => HomePageState();
}

class HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  final FirebaseMessaging firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
  final ScrollController listScrollController = ScrollController();

  late AuthProvider authProvider;
  String? currentUserId;
  late MainProvider mainProvider;
  Debouncer searchDebouncer = Debouncer();
  StreamController<bool> btnClearController = StreamController<bool>();
  TextEditingController searchBarTec = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    mainProvider = context.read<MainProvider>();

    if (authProvider.getUserFirebaseId()!.isNotEmpty == true) {
      currentUserId = authProvider.getUserFirebaseId()!;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
    registerNotification();
    listScrollController.addListener(scrollListener);
  }

//more code below
```

This code is from a Demo: [Chat App with Flutter](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MOHE68LI5Eg&ab_channel=QuangDuyTran)

How do I initialize the fields for authProvider, mainProvider etc?

Comment: i do somethime having problem liek that actually for i did is remove late just the call and variable itself so try both of this AuthProvider authProvider or AuthProvider? authProvider

Comment: When I do just ```AuthProvider authProvider```, I get ```Non-nullable instance field 'authProvider' must be initialized``` error. And for ```AuthProvider? authProvider```, I get ```Null check operator used on a null value``` error too.

Comment: try add it directly like AuthProvider authProvider = authProvider.getUserFirebaseId(); try

Comment: It shows the error ```A value of type 'String?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'AuthProvider'```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Late initialization error` means that a variable marked as `late` (in your case authProvider) was not initialized before it was accessed.

on a widget the first thing you execute is the constructor and then you execute the initstate. your constructor has nothing and initstate reads `authProvider.getUserFirebaseId()`.

If you take a look at the video's github page, you will see that before calling `authProvider`, they initialize it by running the following line:

```
authProvider = context.read<AuthProvider>();
homeProvider = context.read<HomeProvider>();
```

If you are following a tutorial, the tutorial is either outdated or not complete if it has this sort of error.

Comment: Wow, I totally did not see that silly mistake. Thank you!